# Own validator in Phalcon.. How to use created own validator

Tags: php, forms, validation, phalcon

How can I use my created validator?

I have model in  models/Posts.php

```
<?php
class Posts extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{ 
     public function validation()
     {
         $this->validation(new OtherThanActive([
             'field' => 'title'
         ]));

         return ($this->validationHasFailed() != true);
     }
}
?>
```

And I created validator in /app/validators/PostsValidators.php
(I added in config and loader this dir)

Code of validator:

```
<?php
class OtherThanActive extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate(Validation $validator, $attr)
    {
        $postId = $this->getOption('postId');
        $field = $this->getOption('field');

        $active = \Posts::findFirst($attr['postId'])->users->active; 
        if($attr['postTitle'] == $active)
        {
            $validator->appendMessage(new Message('Here is error message...'));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

When I want use my walidator in model I have error that OtherThanActive class not found.

How in phalcon we can include own validators ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you are, but, my guess is you're not loading the validators folder.

Use the Phalcon loader to do so:

```
(new \Phalcon\Loader())
    ->registerDirs(['app/validators/'])
    ->register();
```